# Adding/removing styling on popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap3 and specifically it's JS component called [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

I would like too add class to an element when it is clicked and popover shows and remove that class when it is clicked again and the popover is removed.

Here's my code when I show/hide popover:

```
$('body').popover({
    selector: '.clickMeEm',
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: 'right'
});

<span class="clickMeEm" data-toggle="popover" data-content="message here"></span>
```

Now, bootstrap offers event handlers that I'd like to use **shown.bs.popover** and **hidden.bs.popover**

Because I have multiple popovers on the page, obviously I need to apply styles only to the elements that are next to the popovers.

```
$('.clickMeEm').next('.popover').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
});

$('.clickMeEm').next('.popover').on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
  $(this).removeClass('clicked');
});
```

So, the class needs to apply to the element that's clicked, and not the popover. The popover works fine in my code.

For some reason it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: You could simply use `$('.clickMeEm').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a class to your popover, you can pass HTML to your popover content (via `data-content`), and assign a class or id to it.

HTML:

```
<span class="clickMeEm" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<span id='message'>message here</span>">Click for popover</span>
```

In your JS add `html: true` as a parameter.

```
$('body').popover({
    selector: '.clickMeEm',
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: 'right',
    html: true
});
```

Then you can trigger event and reference the relevant id / class (in this example, `#message`:

```
$('.clickMeEm').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  $('#message').closest('.popover').addClass('clicked'); //adds class on same element as `.popover`
});

$('.clickMeEm').on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
  $('#message').closest('.popover').removeClass('clicked');
});
```

### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/r2C605FEL1)

Comment: What element do you want the `clicked` class on? The same one as `clickMeEm`?

Comment: Actually, it worked in the bootply but not in real code. Because I add clickable elements with another function, I have to use delegate to trigger popover. When I simply click the element, nothing happens.  :(

Comment: Ok well it's not very clear what you want - you can see already 3 answers providing information and none of them are what you want so you should try to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You use your jQuery selectors wrong. The `.next('.popover')` needs to refer to `$(this)`.

Change your code like this:

```
$('.clickMeEm').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  $(this).next('.popover').addClass('clicked');
});

$('.clickMeEm').on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
  $(this).next('.popover').removeClass('clicked');
});
```

**[Working Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/eaFfEVwGDd)**

Comment: I think this will apply class to the popover. I need it to be for clicked item.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Then I didn't understand you correctly. Yes, this applies the class to the popover.

Answer (score 0):

Fully functional example here showing and closing multiple popovers when clicked somewhere outside of your buttons as well, just copy and paste JS code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7h7ptjzh/

```
$(function () {

    $('body').popover({
        selector: '.clickMeEm',
        trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'right'
    });

    $('.clickMeEm').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
      $('.clicked').popover('hide');                  
      $(this).addClass('clicked');       
    });     

    $('.clickMeEm').on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
      $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    });

    $('body').click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass("clickMeEm"))
        {
            $('.clickMeEm').popover('hide');
        }       
    });

});
```